# I can't quite get my generic class to work in Java

Tags: java

I have the following execution which contains three methods. `plus` adds a string to the class, `minus` removes it, and `empty` checks and returns true if there are no more strings stored.

```
private static void test() {
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    stack.plus("hello1");
    stack.plus("hello2");
    stack.plus("hello3");
    stack.plus("hello4");

    while (!stack.empty()) {
        System.out.println(stack.minus());
    }

    stack.plus("a1");
    stack.plus("a2");
    stack.plus("a3");
    stack.plus("a4");
    stack.minus();
    stack.minus();
    stack.plus("a5");
    stack.plus("a6");

    while (!stack.empty()) {
        System.out.println(stack.minus());
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("hiding")
public class Stack<String> {

    private String e;

    public void plus(String e) {
        this.e= e;
    }

    public String minus() {
        return e;   
    }

    public boolean empty() {
        if(e != null) {
        }return false;
    }
}
```

The output should be:

> hello4
>
> hello3
>
> hello2
>
> hello1
>
> a6
>
> a5
>
> a2
>
> a1

My program at the moment keeps looping infinitely at "hello4" and I can't quite figure out how to fix my `empty` function. I suspect that method is my main issue.

Comment: Your stack never 'adds' or 'removes' anything. It just sets or gets a single string field, it doesn't remember anything about previous values.

Comment: Your `empty` function always returns false

Comment: Would I need to add an Arraylist to one of my methods to store the elements? Or is that not necessary?

Comment: You do need to use an array or list of some form, you will be adding multiple items to your stack and each item needs to be stored, essentially what you have implemented is not a stack. You should check out this link which includes a few different stack implementations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629876/stack-implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand the syntax of generics. In your Stack class, the generic parameter `String` behaves a lot more like a variable, not like the String class.

```
//DataType is substituted for whatever you tell it in <...> when making a Stack object
public class Stack<DataType> { 

    private List<DataType> memory = new ArrayList<>();

    public void push(DataType e) {
        memory.add(e);
    }

    public DataType pop() {
        if(memory.isEmpty())
           return null;
        int lastIndex = memory.size()-1;
        DataType element = memory.get(lastIndex); //get last element of memory
        memory.remove(lastIndex); //remove it from the stack
        return element; //return it   
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return memory.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

which you can then use like you already are:

```
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>(); //DataType in Stack becomes String
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was advised to first try out generic classes by defining the type as "String" before trying to implement a more generic datatype. But it seems like the fundamental problem in my code still persists regardless.

Comment: your `minus()` method never sets `e` to `null`, hence the `empty()` is always false and your `while(!stack.empty())` never terminates.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to how I can define my `minus` method?

Comment: There you go, I made you a little stack. I didn't try it, so no guarantees given.

Comment: I see, this does make sense. So essentially, it's not possible to create a stack without defining an Arraylist to store it in?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be an ArrayList, but you definitely need some kind of datastructure to hold multiple pieces of data. An array would also do (although you'd have to resize it if it gets full which basically gives you an ArrayList again). You don't really get to store a whole lot of things in a single variable (maybe a long String of serialized Objects, but we're getting really esoteric there)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I can see that the code is having some difficulties executing the correct output when the `pop` method appears twice in the main argument. For instance instead of removing "a3", it keeps it and removes "a2" instead.

Comment: It matches your expected output when I try it. Are you sure you're doing the right operations?

Comment: I think the issue is if they contain the same string. For instance, if you change "a4" to "a2", then it doesn't remove the last element in the stack.

Comment: Yep, that's actually a bug because removing by object reference can't tell which copy of the String you want to remove and it ends up just kicking out the first it finds. Try with removing by index instead `memory.remove(memory.size()-1)`. It's probably also smart to store the index-calculation in a variable because depending on the underlying datastructure size() might be a quite expensive operation.